# Why is my nx plugin generator trying to use angular devkit schematics?

Tags: nrwl-nx

I am the developer of the nx plugin [@gb-nx/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gb-nx/cli/v/2.0.0-alpha.4)

I am making use of `wrapAngularDevkitSchematic` from `@nrwl/devkit/ngcli-adapter` in other plugins so I'm familiar with that I think.

I dug into the stack trace (below) and see that `@angular-devkit/schematics/tools...` is looking for a `schematics` key in my plugin's `package.json`.

Why is angular devkit being involved here? Is it because I have it in my `node_modules` for other plugins?

```
Error: Package "@gb-nx/cli" was found but does not support schematics.
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.resolve (D:\ha\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:54:23)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (D:\ha\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\node-module-engine-host.js:81:37)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (D:\ha\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\file-system-engine-host-base.js:118:27)
    at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (D:\ha\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:162:40)
    at SchematicEngine.createCollection (D:\ha\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:155:43)
    at getCollection (D:\ha\node_modules\nx\src\adapter\ngcli-adapter.js:66:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ha\node_modules\nx\src\adapter\ngcli-adapter.js:545:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\ha\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:118:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had removed the `cli: nx` entry from my schema causing the `nx` command to think it was a angular/devkit schematic instead of a generator.